# getting error while parsing JSON response from retrofit and store it in realm

Tags: android, realm, retrofit

> I am parsing this json response from the retrofit. without extending
>   RealmObject i can successfully parsed but when i extend RealmObject to
>   my model class its gets error.
>
> I think here  "wrong_ans": [] contains array so i putted MyObject
>   class which  extending RealmObject but eventhoght its not working

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

JSON RESPONE

```
[
    {
        "testName": "super q test id",
        "wrong_ans": [],
        "correct_ans": [],
        "attempted_que": [
            "test-super-topic-1-2"
        ],
        "skipped_que": [
            "test-super-topic-1-2"
        ],
        "review_que": [],
        "totalQuestions": [
            "test-super-topic-1-1",
            "test-super-topic-1-2",
            "time-and-work-2-1",
            "time-and-work-2-2",
            "time-and-work-2-3",
            "time-and-work-2-4",
            "time-and-work-2-5"
        ],
        "test_id": "super-q-test-id"
    }
]
```

CRETE POJO CLASS

```
public class FinishUserExam extends RealmObject implements Serializable{

    @SerializedName("testName")
    @Expose
    private String testName;
    @SerializedName("wrong_ans")
    @Expose
    private RealmList<MyObject> wrongAns = null;
    @SerializedName("correct_ans")
    @Expose
    private RealmList<MyObject> correctAns = null;
    @SerializedName("attempted_que")
    @Expose
    private RealmList<RealmString> attemptedQue = null;
    @SerializedName("skipped_que")
    @Expose
    private RealmList<RealmString> skippedQue = null;
    @SerializedName("review_que")
    @Expose
    private RealmList<MyObject> reviewQue = null;
    @SerializedName("totalQuestions")
    @Expose
    private RealmList<RealmString> totalQuestions = null;
    @SerializedName("test_id")
    @Expose
    private String testId;

    public String getTestName() {
        return testName;
    }

    public void setTestName(String testName) {
        this.testName = testName;
    }

    public RealmList<MyObject> getWrongAns() {
        return wrongAns;
    }

    public void setWrongAns(RealmList<MyObject> wrongAns) {
        this.wrongAns = wrongAns;
    }

    public RealmList<MyObject> getCorrectAns() {
        return correctAns;
    }

    public void setCorrectAns(RealmList<MyObject> correctAns) {
        this.correctAns = correctAns;
    }

    public RealmList<RealmString> getAttemptedQue() {
        return attemptedQue;
    }

    public void setAttemptedQue(RealmList<RealmString> attemptedQue) {
        this.attemptedQue = attemptedQue;
    }

    public RealmList<RealmString> getSkippedQue() {
        return skippedQue;
    }

    public void setSkippedQue(RealmList<RealmString> skippedQue) {
        this.skippedQue = skippedQue;
    }

    public RealmList<MyObject> getReviewQue() {
        return reviewQue;
    }

    public void setReviewQue(RealmList<MyObject> reviewQue) {
        this.reviewQue = reviewQue;
    }

    public RealmList<RealmString> getTotalQuestions() {
        return totalQuestions;
    }

    public void setTotalQuestions(RealmList<RealmString> totalQuestions) {
        this.totalQuestions = totalQuestions;
    }

    public String getTestId() {
        return testId;
    }

    public void setTestId(String testId) {
        this.testId = testId;
    }


}
```

CONVERTING OBJECT CLASS TO MYOBJECT CLASS

```
public class MyObject implements RealmModel {
    private Object mObject;
    public MyObject(){
    }

    public MyObject(Object mObject) {
        this.mObject = mObject;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return mObject;
    }

    public void setValue(Object mObject) {
        this.mObject = mObject;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return mObject.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some java code where you used these models.The error is stating that you are getting response as String not object,so check response.

Comment: That's not a POJO class. BTW the problem is that you think GSON knows that RealmString is a "string" (it's not, it's an object). But it doesn't know how to deserialize a String as RealmString, so if you do want to use the same class for defining your Realm schema AND for receiving an external API response which I personally think is horrible practice, then you'll most likely need to write a custom deserializer for FinishUserExam class.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove '[' and ']' at the begining and end of your json, so  your json should be like this

```
{
        "testName": "super q test id",
        "wrong_ans": [],
        "correct_ans": [],
        "attempted_que": [
            "test-super-topic-1-2"
        ],
        "skipped_que": [
            "test-super-topic-1-2"
        ],
        "review_que": [],
        "totalQuestions": [
            "test-super-topic-1-1",
            "test-super-topic-1-2",
            "time-and-work-2-1",
            "time-and-work-2-2",
            "time-and-work-2-3",
            "time-and-work-2-4",
            "time-and-work-2-5"
        ],
        "test_id": "super-q-test-id"
    }
```

not this

```
[
    {
        "testName": "super q test id",
        "wrong_ans": [],
        "correct_ans": [],
        "attempted_que": [
            "test-super-topic-1-2"
        ],
        "skipped_que": [
            "test-super-topic-1-2"
        ],
        "review_que": [],
        "totalQuestions": [
            "test-super-topic-1-1",
            "test-super-topic-1-2",
            "time-and-work-2-1",
            "time-and-work-2-2",
            "time-and-work-2-3",
            "time-and-work-2-4",
            "time-and-work-2-5"
        ],
        "test_id": "super-q-test-id"
    }
]
```

Comment: JSON response is array of objects so it should be "[" and "]" bracket